# Ksp of calcium hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, solutions

What would the Ksp of calcium hydroxide be at around room temp (66 Fahrenheit) and 1 atm of pressure? I know the Ksp value varies with temperature, but is there a notable difference from 20 degrees C to 25 degrees C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [IUPAC Solubility Data Series Volume 52, *Alkaline Earth Hydroxides in Water and Aqueous Solutions* (1992)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-023920-0.50010-1), the best fitting to experimental solubility values of calcium hydroxide in water was obtained with a three-parameter equation:

$\ln\left({b/{\text{mol kg}}^{-1}}\right) = 86.1534 - 3492.14/({T/{\text{K}}}) - 13.7494\,\ln({T/{\text{K}}})$

where $b$ is molality and $T$ is temperature.

The results have a standard uncertainty of

$\sigma \left( b \right) = 1.7 \times {10^{ - 4}}\;{\text{mol k}}{{\text{g}}^{ - 1}}$

over the temperature range from 273.15 K to 623.15 K.

---

For

${T_1} = 20\;^\circ\text{C} = 293.15\;{\text{K}}$

the three-parameter equation reads

$\begin{aligned}
  \ln\left({{b_1}/{\text{mol kg}^{-1}}}\right) =  & \;86.1534 - 3492.14/({T_1}/{\text{K)}} - 13.7494\,\ln({T_1}/{\text{K)}} \\ 
   =  & \;86.1534 - 3492.14/(293.15\;{\text{K}}/{\text{K)}} - 13.7494\,\ln(293.15\;{\text{K}}/{\text{K)}} \\ 
   =  & \; {-}3.8651 \\ 
  {b_1}/{\text{mol kg}^{-1}} =  & \;0.02096 \\ 
  {b_1} =  & \;0.02096\;{\text{mol kg}^{-1}} \\ 
\end{aligned} $

In the same way for

${T_2} = 25\;^\circ\text{C} = 298.15\;{\text{K}}$

the three-parameter equation reads

$\begin{aligned}
  \ln\left({{b_2}/{\text{mol kg}^{-1}}}\right) =  & \;86.1534 - 3492.14/({T_2}/{\text{K)}} - 13.7494\,\ln({T_2}/{\text{K)}} \\ 
   =  & \;86.1534 - 3492.14/(298.15\;{\text{K}}/{\text{K)}} - 13.7494\,\ln(298.15\;{\text{K}}/{\text{K)}} \\ 
   =  & \; {-}3.8978 \\ 
  {b_2}/{\text{mol kg}^{-1}} =  & \;0.02029 \\ 
  {b_2} =  & \;0.02029\;{\text{mol kg}^{-1}} \\ 
\end{aligned} $

Thus, taking into account the above-mentioned uncertainty, the calculated solubility of calcium hydroxide in water is

${b_1} = \left( {{\text{0}}{\text{.02096}} \pm 0.00017} \right)\;{\text{mol kg}^{-1}}$ at a temperature of ${T_1} = 20\;^\circ\text{C}$

and

${b_2} = \left( {{\text{0}}{\text{.02029}} \pm 0.00017} \right)\;{\text{mol kg}^{-1}}$ at a temperature of ${T_2} = 25\;^\circ\text{C}$.

Comment: Interesting related read: [William B. Euler, Louis J. Kirschenbaum, and Ben Ruekberg; *J. Chem. Educ.*, **2000**, *77* (8), p 1039](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021%2Fed077p1039)   ([mirror](http://www.academia.edu/792008/Determination_of_Ksp_G0_H0_and_S0)).

Comment: Thank you. Ah, so the $T/K$ value was just to get rid of the units.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes. Generally, such _numerical value equations_ are deprecated; the use of _quantity equations_ is normally preferred and is strongly recommended. However, logarithms of units are ugly; thus, it is easier to eliminate the units and use a numerical value equation in this case. Anyway, this equation is not based on any chemical theory; it is just an arbitrary equation that sufficiently describes the experimental data.